# Counting and looping through multiple arrays within object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm basically just trying to loop through a series of arrays (dynamically created) and output the results in the console. The debugger is telling me that `this.allitems[i]` is undefined. How do I loop through each array in the allItems object?

```
var warehouse = {
  allItems: {
    shirts:[],
    shorts:[]
  },

 // Counts how many arrays are in the object 
 countArraysInAllItems: function(obj){
    var size = 0,key;
    for(key in obj){
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
  },

  // Display the items from the arrays (in no particular order)
  displayItems: function(){
    var allItemsLength = this.countArraysInAllItems(this.allItems);

    for(var i=0; i<allItemsLength; i++){
      var itemSubArray = this.allItems[i];

      for(var j=0; j<itemSubArray.length; j++){
        var itemType = this.itemSubArray[j].itemType;
        var itemName = this.itemSubArray[j].itemName;
        var itemQuantity = this.itemSubArray[j].itemQuantity;

        console.log('Type:' + itemType + '\n' + 
                  'Name: ' + itemName + '\n' +  
                  'Qty:' + itemQuantity);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: `allItems` is an object, not an array. So you should do like `allItems.shirts[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by other answers, allItems is an object, so you cannot iterate in it as an array.

Here is my solution, with 2 `for..in` loops, making the code less verbose :

```
var warehouse = {
  allItems: {
    shirts:[
      {
        itemType: "type1",
        itemName: "shirt1",
        itemQuantity: 1
      },
      {
      itemType: "type2",
      itemName: "shirt2",
      itemQuantity: 10
    }
    ],
    shorts:[
      {
        itemType: "type3",
        itemName: "short1",
        itemQuantity: 4
      }
    ]
  },

// Counts how many arrays are in the object 
countArraysInAllItems: function(obj){
    var size = 0,key;
    for(key in obj){
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
  },

  // Display the items from the arrays (in no particular order)
  displayItems: function(){
    // this variable is not useful right now
    var allItemsLength = this.countArraysInAllItems(this.allItems);

    for(var i in this.allItems){
      var itemSubArray = this.allItems[i];

      for(var j in itemSubArray){
        var itemType = itemSubArray[j].itemType;
        var itemName = itemSubArray[j].itemName;
        var itemQuantity = itemSubArray[j].itemQuantity;

        console.log('Type:' + itemType + '\n' + 
                  'Name: ' + itemName + '\n' +  
                  'Qty:' + itemQuantity);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a traditional `for` loop in JS can be used to loop over an array *but not an object*.  If you think about it, it makes sense-- no property in the object is at a specific *index* per se.

What you're looking for is the [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop -- you're already using it for the count, but then for some reason abandon it in your later loop.

Try something like this-- I couldn't test it with the incomplete code/dataset, but I think it'll be closer to what you're looking to accomplish (and you may not even need the `countArraysInAllItems` method anymore):

```
var warehouse = {
  allItems: {
      shirts: [],
      shorts: []
  },

  // Counts how many arrays are in the object 
  countArraysInAllItems: function(obj) {
      var size = 0,
          key;
      for (key in obj) {
          if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
            size++;
          }
      }
      return size;
  },

  // Display the items from the arrays (in no particular order)
  displayItems: function() {
      var allItemsLength = this.countArraysInAllItems(this.allItems);
      var key;
      var j;
      var itemSubArray;
      var itemType;
      var itemName;
      var itemQuantity;

      for (key in this.allItems) {

          if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && Array.isArray(obj[key])) {

            itemSubArray = obj[key];

            for (j = 0; j < itemSubArray.length; j++) {
                itemType = this.itemSubArray[j].itemType;
                itemName = this.itemSubArray[j].itemName;
                itemQuantity = this.itemSubArray[j].itemQuantity;

                console.log('Type:' + itemType + '\n' +
                    'Name: ' + itemName + '\n' +
                    'Qty:' + itemQuantity);
            }

          }

      }
  }
};
```

PS - I made a few other small changes-- firstly, I moved all the `var` declarations to the top of the function scope to manage [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting), and I also included a check to ensure the property of the `allItems` object is, in fact, an array (just in case you were planning on storing other things on the object).

Comment: I can see this as the most comprehensive answer, but I'm getting a `obj` is not defined...

Answer (score 1):

You can use for..in loop. A first loop for allTtems property and another nested loop for the arrays shirts and shorts :

```
var warehouse = {
  allItems: {
    shirts:[1,2,3,],
    shorts:[10,11,12]
  }
};
for (var item in warehouse)
  for (var element in warehouse[item])
     console.log(warehouse[item][element]);
// [ 1, 2, 3 ]
// [ 10, 11, 12 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're married to using a for.. loop, you could do it like so:

```
var warehouse = {
  allItems: {
    shirts:{itemType:"type1", itemName:"name1", itemQuantity:"qty1"},
    shoes:{itemType:"type2", itemName:"name2", itemQuantity:"qty2"}
  },

  // Display the items from the arrays (in no particular order)
  displayItems: function(){
      for (var item in this.allItems) {
        console.log(item);
        var itemType = this.allItems[item].itemType;
        var itemName = this.allItems[item].itemName;
        var itemQuantity = this.allItems[item].itemQuantity;
        console.log('Type: ' + itemType + '\n' +
                  'Name: ' + itemName + '\n' +
                  'Qty: ' + itemQuantity);
      }
    }
}

warehouse.displayItems();
```

Othewrwise, you can (and should) iterate through the Object.keys() as recommended by others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
    Object.keys(this.allItems).forEach(item => {
      console.log(item);
    });
```

More precise answer

```
  const warehouse = {
    allItems: {
        shirts: [
            {
                itemType: '1',
                itemName: '2',
                itemQuantity: '3',
            }
        ],
        shorts: [
            {
                itemType: '5',
                itemName: '6',
                itemQuantity: '7',
            }
        ]
    },

    // Display the items from the arrays (in no particular order)
    displayItems: function() {
        Object.keys(this.allItems).forEach(items => {
            Object.keys(this.allItems[items]).forEach(item => {
                const {itemType, itemName, itemQuantity} = this.allItems[items][item];
                console.log(itemType, itemName, itemQuantity);
            });
        });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the object using `Object.keys()` and `Array.prototype.forEach()`. Then use `forEach()` to iterate each array:

```js
var warehouse = {
  allItems: {
    shirts: [{
      itemType: "type1",
      itemName: "shirt1",
      itemQuantity: 1
    }, {
      itemType: "type2",
      itemName: "shirt2",
      itemQuantity: 10
    }],
    shorts: [{
      itemType: "type3",
      itemName: "short1",
      itemQuantity: 4
    }]
  },
  displayItems: function() {
    var items = this.allItems;
    Object.keys(items).forEach(function(key) {
      items[key].forEach(function(item) {
        console.log('Type:' + item.itemType + '\n' +
          'Name: ' + item.itemName + '\n' +
          'Qty:' + item.itemQuantity);
      });
    });
  }
};

warehouse.displayItems();
```